# Wordpress - Remove https redirects for media files after moving to localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, https

I moved wordpress website with https address to a localhost on LAMP server using All-in-one migrate plugin. Everything moved well except paths to media files (pictures).

Links to pictures in upload folder are broken. And nothing wrong with them except that they have https instead of http.

[Console errors pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSebk.png)

I tried find/replace in wp_posts table, but it doesnt find anything. Tried to use plugin, that seems to do the same - doesnt help.

My .htaccess file is the default one from WP codex.

Weird, that I've done same process of migrating from https to localhost with another wordpress website and everything was fine.

The only difference between them, is that website with problem is using woocommerce plugin. And images are actualy products images. Maybe this will help.

UPDATE: Looks like problem is with all uploaded media files. I just've uploaded new file, and it's not showing neither. Some problems with apache configuration?

UPDATE2: Found out that this is 301 redirect problem. But where does it comes from? What to do to cancel those redirects? Do I need to edit .htaccess?

[Screenshot of network tab for correspong images. Gray ones are http versions and red ones - are redirected to https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq5ui.png)

Comment: woocommerce has its own tables, try searching in them (also to narrow it down you can use pma or adminer to just look for `https` in every table every row) if its not in the db then search the codebase, also you don't need a plugin to migrate, can just use wp-cli https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't help. In database there are no https... There is some weird redirect working, even though the src attribute of imgs has HTTP in its address in chrome webtools, when I directly open this link it redirects to https link with error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things, that I would recommend you to check.

1. Check your settings in the database **_options** table in the fields **siteurl** and **home**. You should have there http://domain-name
2. Also you need to check your **wp-config.php**. There might be rules added regarding siteurl and home using incorrect protocol.
3. There might be some plugins installed, which can trigger this https redirect, such as **Really Simple SSL**, or **cache** plugins, which also have settings regarding https.
4. And finally, check your theme code, if it is a custom theme, it also can be configured to use https  in some cases.

Comment: 1,2,3,4 checked, not helping. Everything is fine, no https.

Looks like the problem is only with uploads, even new uploads are not showing. Neither in admin panel, nor on front-end.

Comment: I see. In this case, I suppose, it will be easier to migrate the website (or just database) one more time without using a plugin. I hope this article will be helpful https://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/

Comment: After some more investigation I found out that i might add some rules to .htaccess. Because it looks like some problem with redirects only.

The thing is, as I wrote in my post, that I migrate with this plugin all the time, done more than 20 migrations without any problems, except this website :(

Comment: Got you! The only idea, what else you might check is - go to `/wp-admin/options.php` and check this parameter `upload_url_path`. If it is empty, you might try to setup it to your WP, which is `http://local_path_to_wp_installation/wp-content/uploads/`

Comment: there is only relative path... 
I wrote another update to my post that this is definitely 301 redirect problem. Just need to understand where does it come from

Comment: Thank you for this additional information. Could you please try to change `upload_url_path` - which should have the URL to your uploads. There is another parameter `upload_path` - it should be empty. 
And one more thing to check - maybe you have this `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` in `wp-config.php` which triggers the redirect.

Comment: `Options.php` has only this: 
`if ( get_option( 'upload_url_path' ) || ( get_option( 'upload_path' ) != 'wp-content/uploads' && get_option( 'upload_path' ) ) )
{
$allowed_options['media'][] = 'upload_path';
$allowed_options['media'][] = 'upload_url_path';
}`

And honestly, I don't know what to change in here. 

About force ssl - no, it's not there. I also tried to set this rule to false, not helping.

Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: I'm sorry for getting you incorrect information. I was talking about `wp-admin` panel, just forgot to mention it! :) So, the right path to check these parameters is this URL `http://yoursite/wp-admin/options.php`

Comment: That's exactly what you'd mentioned. And the code I posted is from that file

Comment: Also I got this in request data: Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently (from disk cache)

What mean from disk cache? That's very confusing to me. Maybe I just need to purge disk cache? All the caching on WP is off. But disk cache? Is this related to server config?

Comment: BTW, have you tried to open this website from another browser or in an incognito mode? It might be a local cache issue, so you just need to clear it - there are a few ways how to do it in different browsers.

Comment: Tried that also... different browsers, clearing cache. Nope. Some freaky 301 redirect is somewhere. I also tried to put this inside `functions.php`: `remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');`
And guess what? It didnt work too!

Comment: As for options `http://yoursite/wp-admin/options.php` I was talking about that
https://clip2net.com/s/4ek7kNj 

Did it work for you?

Comment: oh wow, didnt know about that! Both fields are empty

Comment: In this case you might put in `upload_url_path` `http://local_path_to_wp_installation/wp-content/uploads/` which is an URL path to uploads and check it it will work

Comment: Nope. Didnt work too... I'm reinstalling this installation because something weird is going on with it. Now it doesnt save posts in chrome. And works fine in firefox. You could think that this is a problem of chrome, but another wordpress installation on my local server is working completely fine.

Comment: I guess, it should be the best option in this case. And I would also recommend you no to use plugins  to move Wordpress, because in my practice, I've seen that plugins were restored the database incorrectly by not adding indexes and key to the tables, as well as rewriting incorrectly sanitized data of some themes, and so on.  So, it might take too much time to debug the issue, comparing to time that you need to spend for the manual migration.